# Extract specific topic value from RDD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am trying to read in spark from kafka topics like below :

```
Map<TopicAndPartition, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(new TopicAndPartition("A", 0), 1L);
        map.put(new TopicAndPartition("B", 0), 1L);

        JavaInputDStream<Map.Entry> topicMessages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                                                                            jssc,
                                                                            String.class,
                                                                            String.class,
                                                                            StringDecoder.class,
                                                                            StringDecoder.class,
                                                                            Map.Entry.class,
                                                                            kafkaParams,
                                                                            map,
                                                                            messageAndMetadata -> 
                                                                                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(messageAndMetadata.topic(),
                                                                                                              messageAndMetadata.message())
                                                                          );
```

Now the **topicMessage** has all the values in key and value format like below:

```
A="04/15/2015","18:44:28"
A="04/15/2015","18:44:28"
A="04/15/2015","18:44:28"
B="04/15/2016","18:44:28"
B="04/15/2014","18:44:28"
```

How can I extract values of particular topics.
Something like below for topic named `B`

```
"04/15/2016","18:44:28"
"04/15/2014","18:44:28"
```

Comment: Why don't u just read from topic `B`. Is there any specific use reading from both topics `A` and `B` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you  want the rows for a given topic, you just need to do:

```
JavaPairDStream<String> rowsFromTopicB = topicMessages.filter( entry -> entry.getKey().toString().equals("B")).map(entry -> entry.getValue().toString())
```

Comment: I think it should be JavaDStream<Entry> .How can I remove key from the line

Comment: Yes you're right. Sorry, I update the asnwer properly, with the answer to this your new question too